# Pattern-matching & existential type

Tags: scala

Why doesn't this work? Scala should understand in the case of `case HasInts`, that `outer.type <: HasInts.type`. What's a workaround (without removing the type member)?

```
sealed trait Outer {
  type Inner
}

case object HasInts extends Outer {
  override type Inner = Int
}

def id(outer: Outer): outer.Inner =
  outer match {
    case HasInts => 0
  }
```

*Edit:*

On the otherhand, if we change the type member from existential to universal, it compiles.

```
sealed trait Outer[Inner]

case object HasInts extends Outer[Int]

def id[I](outer: Outer[I]): I =
  outer match {
    case HasInts => 0
  }
```

Why would it work in first case and not the second? They're arguably identical (and indeed, in Dotty they will be.)

Comment: There is actually no underlying difference between the two definitions of `Outer`. They are in fact equivalent. You could have written your definition of `id` as: `def id[I](outer: Outer { type Inner = I }): I = ...`. Type field does not mean existential type.

Answer (score 2):

Dependent Types. There is no particular way for the compiler to determine what `outer.Inner` is when you return a `Int`. The error puts it well:

```
scala> def id(outer: Outer): outer.Inner =
     |   outer match {
     |     case x@ HasInts => 0 : HasInts.Inner
     |   }
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : HasInts.Inner
    (which expands to)  Int
 required: outer.Inner
           case x@ HasInts => 0 : HasInts.Inner
                                ^
```

The compiler particularly knows that it is an `Int`. But the method definition says it returns `outer.Inner`. Statically with dependent types, it has no other information apart from `outer.Inner`, which basically conveys nothing. For example, with below change it will work:

```
sealed trait Outer {
  type Inner >: Int
}
```

Or you could:

```
sealed trait Outer {
  type Inner 
  def f: Inner
}

case object HasInts extends Outer {
  override type Inner = Int  
  def f:Inner = 23
}

def id(outer: Outer): outer.Inner = outer.f
```

I am not sure if one must go towards dependent types as its slightly difficult to get them right (They might even be removed in future [versions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=e687bFp2FT4#t=1200) once dotty comes in). If I can, I would rather use `Outer[T]`

Comment: I disagree. If the clause `case HasInts` succeeds then the compiler knows that in that case, outer.type <: HasInts.type and because HasInts.Inner is final and = Int, that the return type (in that case) is Int. As to what the underlying return type of the fn is, it will (should?) be whatever you get when you do the same thing but make the Inner type member a universal type (in case I've got my lingo wrong I mean, Outer[Inner].)

Answer (score 1):

Scala simply doesn't use the fact that `outer` matches `HasInts` to refine the type of `outer`. Just like a much simpler case:

```
val x: Object = ...
x match {
  case _: String => x.length
}
```

doesn't compile, and instead you have to write `case s: String => s.length`.

So it still needs to show that `0` has type `outer.Inner` for `outer: Outer`, and of course it can't.

For workarounds, in addition to the ones Jatin mentions, there is the brute-force

```
(outer match {
   case HasInts => 0
 }).asInstanceOf[outer.Inner]
```

Of course, this means you have to check your types are correct instead of the compiler!

For the edit: there is special support for the type parameter case in the compiler

> [In the method case, what you have here is a GADT: Patterns determine the type parameters of an corresponding methods in the scope of a pattern case.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/M9DK5AQCoeA/R3Q_tzFz7QAJ)

But there is no such support for type members, and I expect adding it would be non-trivial.

Comment: Yuck! What purpose could this "workaround" possibly serve?

Comment: Asserting the program is valid even though the compiler can't prove that it is. Like in this case, where inside the branch we do know `outer == HasInts` and thus `0` _is_ an `outer.Inner`, but the compiler doesn't.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant by that question: what is the purpose of "asserting the program is valid" if the compiler cannot prove that it is? Or, putting it another way, what is the reason to use scala if you cannot rely on the compiler proving that the program is valid? Wouldn't it be a lot faster and easier to put something together in python or ruby?

Comment: @Dima Both Shapeless and Scalaz need this workaround in a few places: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=asInstanceOf or https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=asInstanceOf. And they would be rather hard to write in Python and Ruby. Search the Scala compiler sources, for that matter.

Comment: that's exactly the point: scala compiler and, to a lesser extent shapless and scalaz exist, so that we do not need to use the "workaround" (I think, "kludge" or "hack" is a better term here). And I disagree that they would be hard to you write in python or ruby: to the contrary, most of that stuff would be absolutely trivial to write in any language that does not offer a strict typing system.

Comment: Ok, let's take a random less-core Scala library. https://github.com/non/spire/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=asInstanceOf Oops, the last search result is _exactly_ this: `def getBound(zbf: ZeroBoundFunction): zbf.Bound = bounds.getOrElseUpdate(zbf, zbf(this)).asInstanceOf[zbf.Bound]`.

Comment: In fact, I'd be happy if you name _one_ major Scala library which doesn't need this workaround anywhere. Of those I just checked, `FastParse` comes closest, with just 2 uses in a single place for 2.10 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Because the return type of a function cannot depend on the argument, it has to be static. Consider this:

```
case object HasStrings extends Outer {
  override type Inner = Int
}

val list = Seq(HasInts, HasStrings).map { obj => id(obj) }
```

If what you are trying to do worked, than the above line would be valid. But what could the type of the resulting `list` possibly be?

I think, you are looking for a generic type rather than type members. (BTW, this is *not* "existential types", that's a completely different beast).

Comment: "Because the return type of a function cannot depend on the argument, it has to be static." Yes, in Scala it can, search for path-dependent types. In the example you give, the result type is `Seq[x.Inner forSome { val x: Outer }]`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov not really. The type actually is `Outer{type Inner >: String with Int}#Inner`, but the syntactical nuances are beyond the point. The point is that there is absolutely nothing you can do with the elements of that list without casting them to something useful or just treating them as `Any`. They are neither `String`, nor `Ints`, they present no common interfaces and offer no common properties. This is not what path-dependent  types are intended to do at all. This is just perl code in scala syntax. (Also, path-dependent types isn't quite what you seem to think it is).

Comment: I certainly agree that you can't do anything useful with `list`. This is _completely_ different from the claim that the line is invalid.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov ok, point taken, I misspoke. The line is valid syntactically, but functionally meaningless.

Comment: One of reasons you'd ever want to have a method with signature like this is to avoid mixing up values from different `Outer`s (e.g. imagine `Outer` to be `Compiler` and `Inner` to be `Var`), in which case `list` being useless is a good thing.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov no, "list being useless" is _not_ "a good thing" in that case. A good thing would be a list, that is impossible to create. That is achievable, but, of course, you'd have to give up relying on your "workarounds" in order to have it (otherwise, you can't even claim that it is useless, let alone "a good thing" - `list.head.asInstanceOf[Int]` still works ... ;))